# When i try to migrate in laravel with postgres while running in docker i got an error like could not find driver

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

When i tried to run php artisan migrate within my running container i got error like could not find driver that i think not properly installed postgres i included the code and error below help me to find this.

My docker file

```
FROM php:fpm-alpine

RUN set -ex \
  && apk --no-cache add \
    postgresql-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pgsql

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

COPY . .

RUN composer install

WORKDIR /var/www/html

CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8080

EXPOSE 8080
```

My docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'

services:
  php_3:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"

  postgres_3:
    image: postgres:12.3-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "5431:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
      POSTGRES_DB: lara_3
```

.env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=postgres_3
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=lara_3
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

My containers are running and laravel also running but if i tried to migrate tables with my docker container `docker-compose exec php_3 sh` i am getting error like this.

```
/var/www/html # php artisan migrate

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = public and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:703
    699▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    700▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    701▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    702▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 703▕             throw new QueryException(
    704▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    705▕             );
    706▕         }
    707▕     }

      +33 vendor frames 
  34  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run command and install postgres extension :

```
docker-php-ext-install pdo_pgsql pgsql
```

Comment: Solved the issue now everything works fine. but when i try to build multiple warnings and seeing different things is any suggestions to improve this code.

Comment: this is a very general question, warnings may be about anything,  in many cases, those are not very much serious things and even in many other cases there are not about your code,  maybe be about the base images layer or anything else. don't worry,  your code seems almost right

Comment: Thank you so much for your great explanation and help.